# Can you clone a git repo and update all packages to latest version

Tags: batch-file, npm, version-control

I am writing a simple script to clone a project that is setup to use Vite w/all eslint and prettier config files already populated. I have looked on NPM site and googled but cant find a suitable answer. The repo has a package.json like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.20",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "vite": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

So my script does a clone

```
git clone https://github.com/mysite/vite-prototype.git %viteApp% && ECHO.
```

and then

```
CD %viteapp% && npm install
```

If I run this script 9 months from now I would like for the packages to all be the latest ones.  Any ideas most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by "latest" ones. For example, your `package.json` contains `"eslint": "^8.1.0"`. If you want to install the latest 8.x but not install 9.x or newer, then remove the `node_modules` directory along with any lock file or shrinkwrap file and then run `npm install`. On Unix-like operating systems, that would look like this:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json npm-shrinkwrap.json yarn.lock && npm install
```

If by latest ones you mean even ignoring semver major changes--so even if it is a breaking change going from (say) 8.x to 9.x or later--then first change the versions throughout your `package.json` to be `*`. So, for example, the ESLint entry would now be `"eslint": "*"`. This is far more likely to result in incompatible dependencies breaking your app so be prepared to handle that. One limitation to this approach is that it will get you the version tagged `latest` on `npm`. If you want, say, the version tagged `next` or `beta` or whatever, you won't get those.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant latest version even if its a jump in major version. I also should have specified this is a Windows .cmd file. I'm not concerned with breaking changes because this only to scaffold a new project with Vite. I'm trying to get back some of the functionality vue-cli gives you out of box. Thanx

Comment: For latest even if it's a jump in major version, then if you're able to change the `package.json` versions to `*` as I suggest in the last paragraph, then that should work (along with removing any lock/shrinkwrap files and existing node_modules directory).

Comment: Argh, `*` will give the `latest` tag but I see in your `package.json` snippet that you are using `next` tags already, so the answer needs to be modified. One problem, though is that not all projects keep their `next` tags ahead of their `latest` tags at all times.    (Specifically, at the time of this writing, vue@latest is 2.x but vue@next is 3.x.)

Comment: Argh part 2 is I can't effectively test with your `package.json` snippet because it is apparently using some versions of plugins that aren't public. At the time of this writing, `@vitejs/plugin-vue` 1.x is publicly available but 2.x is nowhere to be found in the npm registry.